# Proving a one-to-one function with a power set involved

Tags: discrete-mathematics, characteristic-functions

Let A = P({1,2,3,4}).

f : A → A defined by f (X ) = X ∩ {1, 4}.

Can I prove that the function is one-to-one as there is one intersection? Or since there are many 1's and 4's within the power list that repeat, does it mean that it is not a one to one function.

I know that the {1,4} will have one intersection with the power set

( {},{1},{2},{3},{4},{1,2},{1,3},

{1,4},      (intersection)

{2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4},{1,2,3,4})

I am used to proving that a function is one by one by proving that if f(u)=f(v)  then you must have u=v, this is confusing for me. I believe that it is a one-to-one function but I am not sure how to prove it in this context.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What is $f(\{1\})$? What is $f(\{1,2\})$

Edit referring to comment:

- $f(\{1\}) = \{1\} \cap \{1,4\} = \{1\}$
- $f(\{1,2\}) = \{1,2\} \cap \{1,4\} = \{1\}$

So, you have found two elements $A,B \in P(\{1,2,3,4\})$ such that $A \neq B$ and $f(A) = f(B)$.

Comment: I apologise if this is a stupid question. Are you asking if there is an intersection between f({1}) and {1,4}? In that case I would assume that it is {1}. Is that correct

Comment: Your question is not stupid. You just try to get a clear understanding of the concepts you are dealing with. And this is good.

Comment: If you need more clarification; just ask.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to paste a part of my response and it posted my response instead. Is f{1} equal to {1} and f{1,2} also equal to {1}?

Comment: Your function maps sets to sets. Not to elements of the sets in question. This is the crucial point. So, the elements of your domain and of your codomain are sets.

Comment: So since f{1} and f({1,2}), both output {1}, f cannot be one to one.

Comment: Exactly. So it is.

Comment: Also when you wrote f(A)=f(B), does f(A) refer to f({1}) and f(B) refer to f({1,2}). Thank you so much

Comment: Again exactly. That's what it meant.